# Using a dictionary in a class in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I want to use a dictionary in a class (Animals) and want an another class (breeding) to refer to this class. (Animals reads the dictionary and creates an another dictionary with the keys of the first one and the values of 0, 'feed' grows 'strength' with the value of 'food' and the 'breeding' class would make 'children' with the amount of 'strength'.)

The code in the Animals class works, but it does not pass the names (keys) of the dictionary to the breeding class:

" 'breeding' object has no attribute 'strength' "

Does anybody have a suggestion how to solve this?

```
class Animals:  

    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dictionary=dictionary
        self.strength={}
        for name, value in dictionary.items():
            self.strength[name]=0
            setattr(self, name, value)
            print("Name: {} ".format(name))

    def feed(self, name, food):
        self.food=food
        self.strength[name]+= food
        print(self.strength[name])

    def read(self):
        for name in self.my_dict:
            print("Name: {}   Strength: {}".format(name,self.strength[name]))

class breeding(Animals):

    def __init__(self, name,child=0):  
        self.child=child

        if self.strength[name] >= 10:
            child += (self.strength[name]/10)
            self.my_dict[name] = (self.strength[name]%10)
            print("Strength level: {}, number of children: {}".format(self.strength[name], child))
        else: 
            print("Strength level only {}, no new children".format(self.strength[name]))
```

Comment: Please provide more information and preferably tags as well. This seems to be `Python`, but readers shouldn't be guessing it. Tags `class` and `dictionary` are very general unless they're provided with some particular language.

Comment: ```self.my_dict[name] = (self.strengt[name]%10)``` it's not that you spelled strength wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inherit from a class (like in this case `breeding` inherits from `Animals`) you need to invoke `__init__` of the parent class in child class, otherwise it is not executed and all initialization that should happen there does not happen.

That's why you get the error message - because `Animal` "part" of `breeding` was not initialized correctly.

`__init__` in `Animals` gets `dictionary` and that means that `breeding.__init__` should pass `dictionary` when calling `Animals.__init__`.

Do it like this:

```
class breeding(Animals):
    def __init__(self, name, child=0):  
        dictionary = ... # create dictionary that should be passed to parent
        super(breeding, self).__init__(dictionary) # invoke Animal's __init__
        # do other initialization of the `breeding` itself
        ...
```

Comment: @AN_, You should accept the answer as resolving your question.